# Java 6 and SwingUtilities2

Tags: java, swing

There is component within the application that uses  com.sun.java.swing.SwingUtilities2 Now I understand that this class shouldn't be used, but it's a component within the system that uses it.

Therefore since it's no longer available in Java 6 I get a NoClassDefFoundError. How can I get around this issue without having to upgrade the component as I don't yet know if that's an option.

Comment: Are you going to name and shame the provider of the component?

Comment: Is this for a spot fix?  is it possible to get the vendor to do a rebuild for 6?

Comment: @Tom: They've since fixed it, we just don't want to absorb the time and monetary costs. For example, they've improved their API but we don't need any of the improvements (other than this fix). As well we don't know if our code will need an uplift to match the new API (more time costs). And there's of course the "upgrade" cost for the component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have absolutely no other choice, then you should figure out exactly what it was that the class is using from SwingUtilities2, and then make proxies for that functionality in your own SwingUtilities2.  You can then stick it in your own com.sun.java.swing package, which will overlap with the original one, and if the same class loader that loads your component is also aware of SwingUtilities2, then the one will see the other and your application will work.

Depending on what the component is, and what it used out of SwingUtilities2, this could be significantly harder than upgrading it or even rewriting it.

Comment: I agree. Do you have any idea if the source is available anywhere. I understand it's not open source, but someone must have created some kind of class to replace it...

Comment: Other than just decompiling it.

Comment: It looks like they just changed the package name to sun.swing

Comment: In regards to googling it, I did (well before asking here). The issue is that there are several different "versions" of the same code. So which is right? And more importantly, how well do you trust them...

Comment: That's what I got too. The problem is that there is some code in an obfuscated jar that's the culprit. Which unfortunately means I don't have the luxury of just changing the code :(

Comment: Note that the `com.sun.` package could become sealed, the class might be reintroduced without the relevant method, or some other reason why it might break again at any moment.

Comment: Is there a copy in OpenJDK? If not the top hit on google has a Sun copyright at the top so it might be trustworthy.  Either way you'd have to evaluate the code, whether it's worth using and the legalities of doing so.
http://www.javaresearch.org/source/jdk150/com/sun/java/swing/SwingUtilities2.java.html

Answer (score 1):

Da-dum! This is precisely why you should pay attention to those pesky warnings admonishing you not to rely upon internals of the JVM!

Comment: @Rob you assume that @Stephane made the problem he has to support. How do you solve the problem if you had to fix the issue?

Comment: It's actually in a component that was purchased to include in the software. The component, since it's proprietary, is obfuscated. I also had no idea (nor how could you even) know it was using this class.

Comment: Even obfuscated you should be able to see what the code is using. For instance using `strings` on the class files. Not necessarily an interesting thing to do though.

Answer (score 1):

Just a though, I don't know if this would work.

Try pulling out the SwingUtilities2 class and put it in a patch jar, include this jar in your classpath. Hopefully this works until you can change the source.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't quite work. There's a line ((Boolean)c.getClientProperty(AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY)); that always returns null and therefore throws a nullpointerexception.

Comment: Edit the references inside the copied class to refer locally. I think the NP is because it is using the real 6 variables. Although it would be best to get the vender to rebuid a 6 . Some companies do this for quick fixes

Answer (score 1):

The only correct way (out of hacking) is to ask vendor to fix and rebuild this component to Java 6. The possible working way is copy sun.swing.SU2 to com.sun...SU2 and package it into separate jar (e.g. java6fix.jar) and try to run your application. It will be fine if you add this patch jar into jvm bootclasspath. The best patch should be to create own com.sun..SU2 and delegate all calls to sun.swing.SU2. And take a look for different version of component which support Java6 maybe also from different vendor. Also if the problem is only in the mentioned line `((Boolean)c.getClientProperty(AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY));` then you may put your own client property for this component to prevent NPE. When you take this path you can just simply create your own com.sun...SU2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY and call c.setClientProperty(AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, true) on this component. Also try to disable anti aliasing check on component if possible.

Comment: Although it's nice to say, I'm afraid this is an expensive route. The component was built in the JDK 5 error, so I can't fault them for not supporting JDK 6.

Comment: If not, take another path from my suggestions.